# Basic Drupal Modifications

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

On my Drupal site I am using a theme that puts a log-in prompt on the main page. I want to move it to a separate page. How do I do that? Also, once I move or remove it, How would I go about still logging on as the admin?

The home page is here http://www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26/

Update:

Right, the bottom right block.  I solved the problem, as suggested, by removing the block.

The login form on the main page was a Block. You disabled it by going to
Administration >> Structure >> Blocks. There found a list with all
blocks for the current theme.  I just moved the Login Block to the Disabled area at the bottom.

Now I have an issue with the Navigation block.  But that is a subject for another discussion thread

Comment: You mean the "User login" block in the right column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login prompt is a block. Disable it or configure it not to appear on the front page or to only appear on certain pages or whatever.

The URL to access blocks in D7 is: /admin/structure/block

Answer (score 1):

Until you clarify the log-in prompt you talk about, I can already say several things:

- No need to do something special to "move the log in functionnality to a separate page" because it will always be on that page: http://www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26/user. If you want it to be accessible through the menu, just go to `admin>structure>menu` and add a link into the right menu.
- To log in as the admin, just go to http://www.arguemax.com/_drupal-7.26/user like any other user and use your admin username and password normally.

I'm waiting for your edit to complete my answer ;)